# Pandas: how to incrementally add one to column while sum is less than corresponding column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to increment a column by 1 while the sum of that column is less than or equal to a total supply figure. I also need that column to be less than the corresponding value in the 'allocation' column. The supply variable will be dynamic from 1-400 based on user input. Below is the desired output (**Allocation Final** column).

supply = 14

```
| rank | allocation | Allocation Final |
| ---- | ---------- | ---------------- |
| 1    | 12         | 9                |
| 2    | 3          | 3                |
| 3    | 1          | 1                |
| 4    | 1          | 1                |
```

Below is the code I have so far:

```
data = [[1.05493,12],[.94248,3],[.82317,1],[.75317,1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['score','allocation'])

df['rank'] = df['score'].rank()

df['allocation_new'] = 0

#static for testing
supply = 14

for index in df.index:

    while df.loc[index, 'allocation_new'] < df.loc[index, 'allocation'] and df.loc[index, 'allocation_new'].sum() < supply:
        df.loc[index, 'allocation_new'] += 1

print(df)
```

Comment: Hi @afrank1013, you explained what you’re trying to achieve, but can you also describe what problem you are running into when trying to get there? Can you maybe show the code you wrote?

Comment: What if you had allocation `[4,4,4,1]` and value `8`? and allocation `[4,5,4,1]` and value `8`?

Comment: Hi @mozway, in this case the function would allocate available supply `[8]` based on rank until supply is depleted. So 'Allocation Final' for the first list you provided would be `[3, 2, 2, 1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
def allocate(df, supply):
    if supply > df['allocation'].sum():
        raise ValueError(f'Unacheivable supply {supply}, maximal {df["allocation"].sum()}')

    under_alloc = pd.Series(True, index=df.index)
    df['allocation final'] = 0

    while (missing := supply - df['allocation final'].sum()) >= 0:
        assert under_alloc.any()

        if missing <= under_alloc.sum():
            df.loc[df.index[under_alloc][:missing], 'allocation final'] += 1
            return df

        df.loc[under_alloc, 'allocation final'] = (
            df.loc[under_alloc, 'allocation final'] + missing // under_alloc.sum()
        ).clip(upper=df.loc[under_alloc, 'allocation'])

        under_alloc = df['allocation final'] < df['allocation']

    return df
```

At every iteration, we add the missing quotas to any rows that did not reach the allocation yet (rounded down, that’s `missing // under_alloc.sum()`), then using `pd.Series.clip()` to ensure we stay below the allocation.

If there’s less missing quotas than available ranks to which to allocate (e.g. run the same dataframe with supply=5 or 6), we allocate to the first `missing` ranks.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame( {'allocation': {0: 12, 1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 1}, 'rank': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}})
>>> print(allocate(df, 14))
   allocation  rank  allocation final
0          12     1                 9
1           3     2                 3
2           1     3                 1
3           1     4                 1
>>> print(allocate(df, 5))
   allocation  rank  allocation final
0          12     1                 2
1           3     2                 1
2           1     3                 1
3           1     4                 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler version:

```
def allocate(series, supply):
    allocated = 0
    values = [0]*len(series)
    while True:
        for i in range(len(series)):
            if allocated >= supply:
                return values
            if values[i] < series.iloc[i]:
                values[i]+=1
                allocated+=1

        pass
allocate(df['allocation'], 14)
```

output:

```
[9,3,1,1]
```